# Could someone from JFrog join the discussion around testing new versions of pip?

Tags: artifactory

Over at https://discuss.python.org/t/community-testing-of-packaging-tools-against-non-warehouse-indexes/13442/8 they are looking for engagement from commercial vendors who could test pip HEAD against their products and provide feedback. It seems this is something worthwhile for JFrog to do.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined by the [help].

Answer (score -1):

Yes, pip 22.0 seems to have some issue with the header, and working with Artifactory is not seamless. You can refer to this [KB article](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/artifactory-pip-install-doesnt-work-with-pip-22-x/) for a better understanding.

Comment: How does pointing me to a JFrog article indicate that JFrog, the company, is trying to engage with the OpenSource community? That article indicates the opposite: there is no mention of how JFrog reached out to pip maintainers or how they propose to test future versions of pip. The article blames pip for changing something when in fact it is artifactory that was non-standards compliant.